# How do I edit all highlighted instances of a word simultaneously?

Tags: notepad++, keyboard-shortcuts

In Notepad++, whenever you select any word in an HTML document (or in your CSS), similar words are automatically highlighted.

Is there a shortcut I can use to edit all of these highlighted segments at once?

[image: All instances of 'unit' highlighted in Notepad++]

Comment: I don't understant the question... what is your goal? ctrl + h is for replacing

Comment: Double click "unit" for example, highlights all "unit" in the code.. I start typing and it replaces this one unit.. I'd like to replace all, without passing by search&replace window..

Comment: Using `Ctrl`+`Click` you can simultaneously edit many points but you need to do that manually.

Answer (score 20):

Currently, the ability to select all similar text and edit (like the Ctrl+D functionality in Sublime, as mentioned by @George) is not built in to Notepad++ version 6.9.2. It does sound like it will work when Notepad++ [updates the version of Scintilla](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/community/topic/11360/multi-selection-and-multi-edit/2) it uses as the functionality is built in to the [newer version of that](http://www.scintilla.org/ScintillaDoc.html#MultipleSelectionAndVirtualSpace).

The only way to accomplish something similar to the multi-line edit you speak of is to either use the replace function or Notepad++'s version of multi-editing.

## To Find/Replace

1. Highlight the word you would like to replace.
2. Type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to bring up the Replace dialogue.
3. Modify the "Replace with" text.
4. Choose either "Replace" or "Replace All"

## To Multi-Edit

You first need to [enable this feature in Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/features/multi-editing.html). Do this by going to <kbd>Settings</kbd>→<kbd>Preferences</kbd>→<kbd>Editing</kbd> and then enable Multi-Line Edit. Now when you hold Ctrl and click around your text, a cursor will be left at the location of each click. When you're done locating all of the places you'd like to edit, you can start typing. Whatever you type will now appear at each of the locations you left a cursor at.

Comment: Doesn't work. whenever i start typing it only edits one single word. My np version = 7.3.1. What i want to do is comment/uncomment all print statements for debugging purposes.

Comment: @BillyJhon the original question asked how to replace multiple instances of the same word, what you are wanting is completely different.

Comment: @BillyJhon [This answer](https://superuser.com/a/790369/686479) describes how to accomplish the functionality that you want.

Comment: yes. and that is what my question is. Like print statements are all in diiferent parts of the code. so i highlight all of the and edit with # sign. But your solution does not seem to work. and the link you posted refers to block commenting. and that is not what i want.

Comment: @BillyJhon I just tested multi-line edit in **Notepad++ v7.3.1** and it works... Did you enable the feature? [This page](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/features/multi-editing.html) actually discusses the feature. If that does not work for you, then you may have a different problem.

Comment: doesnt work for me. Thanks for the hint anywat, will kepp looking.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138671/discussion-between-joshua-miller-and-billy-jhon).

Comment: How can you type an arrow like that, <kbd>Settings</kbd>→<kbd>Preferences</kbd>→<kbd>Editing</kbd>?

Comment: I found it useful - i made the settings recomended and then double clicked a certain word; then having the word all over the document highlighted clicked (now with CTRL pressed) on all or only on those instances which I wanted to edit simultaneusly; then go to one word from all I marked with a simple click and I could even paste, delete or type whatever and it works everywhere! Another click somewhere else, erases the flags from all the CTRL-clicked words and you can continue in normal mode. Sure enough you can also click on a non highlighted word also and then there the flag is attached too.

Comment: already 8.3.3 version released, still not possible?

Comment: @Suncatcher, looking through the thread I linked in the answer above, it appears that it may now be possible (or at least better) in more recent versions of Notepad++. I have not had a chance to test it out again though.

Comment: neither of the ways mentioned by you are really a solution: replace all is not it, as well as manual selection and multi-editing. The question was about: a) automatic highlight b) automatic edit of all highlighted instances, not manual.

Answer (score 4):

Ctrl + F, enter word, enter replacement. "Hit Replace all".

Comment: Warning to all, if you do it this way then it might replace more than what is highlighted. For example, notepad++ will not highlight instances that are substrings of longer words but the method above will replace those.

Comment: I can't write this as an answer but if you turn on regular expressions and search and replace \bunit\b then only the highlighted words will be replaced. If unit appears in phrases like "opportunity" or "communities" then it won't be replaced.

Comment: Isn't the replace shortcut ***Ctrl + H***? Using ***Ctrl + F*** opens the find menu.

Comment: Make sure to select "Match whole word only", otherwise you may replace more than you expected

Answer (score 1):

There used to be a way that you could just highlight and do something to edit all of the highlighted parts. I know you can click, but there was a way previous you didn't need to do this for everything (and had nothing to do with the find/replace command!)

I should add that the Ctrl+Click option doesn't have to be matching words, so its not really related to the highlighting of similar words

Answer (score 0):

This might be a bit late though...

1. Move your cursor to the start of the the word "unit" in one of your ul block. Just next to " character. Make sure this is the first or last item.
2. Press 'Alt' key on your keyword.
3. Move up (if you have selected the last line) or down (if you have selected the first line) the cursor vertically within its spot (will show just a tiny vertical highlighted line).
4. Type: cool-
   You will see "cool-unit"

If you want to override the word "unit" then:
At the 1-st step select the entire word unit then follow next steps.

Comment: Can you please explaine differently? It doesn't work for me. It's notepad++, right?

Comment: move your cursor to line 7 and put it between " (double quote) and 'u' letter. Press and hold the Alt key. While holding the Alt key- move your cursor vertically up to the line 3 (you will notice cursor blinking on all 5 lines). Type anything you want (say 'cool'). all 5 line will be updated to "cool-unit."
Yes, this is for notepad++ and this trick will work for most editors available, includin MS Word app. For MS Visual Code you will need to press and hold Alt+Shift keys.

Comment: >While holding the Alt key- move your cursor vertically up to the line 3<   
How do you mover the cursor? By mouse or up/down keys?

Comment: drag up from the line 7 to line 3 vertically while holding the Alt key. First: move your cursor to described position then press and hold the alt key, then drag up to line 3 level. You will override vertically highlighted content if you select vertically more than one column. So, if you want to append content then make sure you drag up straight; do not move left or right (notepad++ https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jiI6X7dMa0E, word https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vIbxrddLLj8).

Answer (score -1):

There is a way, but I used a different editor. 
Sublime lets you select multiple areas by highlighting one and hitting CTRL+D, then you get many cursors and you can edit them in parallel.

Comment: This, isn't helpful. The question talks about notepad++.

Comment: So the solution is to use a different editor? I really hope there's a solution for Notepad++, meanwhile. This may be the single most useful feature of Sublime for me, using it all the time ...

Answer (score -1):

See the answer here https://superuser.com/questions/621986/editing-all-instances-of-a-string-in-notepad

Which is:

> CTRL+H to get to the Replace dialog (or Search ==> Replace via the
>   menu).
>
> Input the string to find and input the string to replace it with and
>   then hit the 'replace all' button on the right.