# Notepad++ select two lines in find diolouge

Tags: notepad++

Here is my example.

Can i search for all `bla1's` and the next line below each but exclude everything else?

I want to only find lines 1,2,5,6,11,12

To be able to copy and paste to a new document

[image]

Here is an updated iexample of what it would look like i want to search only for (bla1) and the very next line for each instance of bla1.

```
1.#ext-1gggggtgtgtgtggt(bla1)
2.http://jhh/lkl/path1/
3.#ext-1gggggtgtgtgtggt(bla2)
4.http://jhh/lkl/path22/
5.#ext-1gggggtgtgtgtggt(bla1)
6.http://jhh/lkl/path9/
7.#ext-1gggggtgtgtgtggt(bla5)
8.http://jhh/lkl/path1766/
9.#ext-1gggggtgtgtgtggt(bla4)
10.http://jhh/lkl/path2332/
11.#ext-1gggggtgtgtgtggt(bla1)
12.http://jhh/lkl/path9899/
```

So once each is found or marked i would only have

```
1.#ext-1gggggtgtgtgtggt(bla1)
2.http://jhh/lkl/path1/
3.#ext-1gggggtgtgtgtggt(bla1)
4.http://jhh/lkl/path9/
5.#ext-1gggggtgtgtgtggt(bla1)
6.http://jhh/lkl/path9899/
```

Hopefully this is clearer

First problem solved now the next..

if it was like this

```
#ext-1 img(2018)
http//foldrname/pic111
#ext-1 img(2013)
http//foldrname/pic999
#ext-1 img(2018)
http//foldrname/pic000
#ext-1 img(2016)
http//foldrname/pic87
#ext-1 img(2011)
http//foldrname/pic1111
#ext-1 img(2013)
http//foldrname/pic9998
```

then so if i searched same as before exept (2018) insted of bla1

so after it would be

```
#ext-1 img(2018)
http//foldrname/pic111
#ext-1 img(2018)
http//foldrname/pic000
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the
[ask] link for more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly.

Comment: added image as example

Comment: ive updated question as suggested

Comment: Please, add the text example with expected result, not an image so we can test our solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will remove all lines that is not bla1 and next line.

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^.*bla[^1\r\n].*\R.+(?:\R|\z)`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- *UNCHECK `. matches newline`*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^           # beginning of line
  .*        # 0 or more any character but newline
  bla       # literally bla
  [^1\r\n]  # any character that is not 1 or linebreak
  .*        # 0 or more any character but newline
  \R        # any kind of linebreak (i.e. \r, \n, \r\n)
  .+        # 1 or more any character but newline
  (?:       # non capture group
    \R      # any kind of linebreak (i.e. \r, \n, \r\n)
   |        # OR
    \z      # end of file
  )         # end group
```

**Screen capture (before):**

[image]

**Screen capture (after):**

[image]

Comment: that removed all the bla1 and left everything ease i need it leave the bla1 and remove anything else

Comment: @burrome: No, that didn't, see screen captures

Comment: sorry got it to work.. how would i be able to do this if it was like this (2018) for example,, ive removed pla and replaced with 2018.. but no joy

Comment: @burrome: Please edi tyou question and add real case.

Comment: Edited as requested

Comment: @burrome: See my second answer., if it's OK I will remove this one.

Answer (score 0):

> **To Multi-Edit**
>
> You first need to enable this feature in Notepad++. Do this by going
>   to **Settings → Preferences → Editing** and then enable [Multi-Line
>   Edit](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/features/multi-editing.html). Now when you hold Ctrl and click around your text, a cursor
>   will be left at the location of each click.
>
> *Above answer taken from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10880511/how-do-i-edit-all-highlighted-instances-of-a-word-simultaneously) and answered by [joshua](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1542187/joshua)*

When you're done locating all of the places you'd like to edit,

1. Press **Home** key, all cursors will go to the start of each line
2. Press the **End** key while holding the **Shift** key
3. Press **Down** key

The desired selection will now be done. This involves you to manually place your cursors in the required places and then editing from there.

There are text editors out there like [Sublime](https://www.sublimetext.com/), [Atom](https://atom.io/), etc. that allow you to multiselect based on a word and start editing from there.

Some More info:

- While looking about this topic on the internet, I found that this
  question has been discussed about in the [Notepad++ forums](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/community/topic/11360/multi-selection-and-multi-edit)

Answer (score 0):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^.*\((?!2018)\d{4}\).*\R.+(?:\R|\z)`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- *UNCHECK `. matches newline`*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^           # beginning of line
  .*        # 0 or more any character but newline
  \(        # opening parenthesis
  (?!2018)  # negative lookahead, make sure we haven't 2018 after
  \d{4}     # 4 digits
  \)        # closing parenthesis
  .*        # 0 or more any character but newline
  \R        # any kind of linebreak (i.e. \r, \n, \r\n)
  .+        # 1 or more any character but newline
  (?:       # non capture group
    \R      # any kind of linebreak (i.e. \r, \n, \r\n)
   |        # OR
    \z      # end of file
  )         # end group
```

**Result for given example:**

```
#ext-1 img(2018)
http//foldrname/pic111
#ext-1 img(2018)
http//foldrname/pic000
```

**Screen capture (before):**

[image]

**Screen capture (after):**

[image]